# Why does this generated $\sigma$-algebra contain all the sets that we have information about?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Assume that you have a collection of random variables $\{Y_\gamma: \gamma \in C\}$. Where each is a function $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

We define the $\sigma$-algebra: $\sigma(y_\gamma: \gamma\in C)$ as $\sigma(\{\omega \in \Omega: Y_\gamma(\omega)\in B, \gamma \in C, b \in \mathcal{B}\})$. Where $\mathcal{B}$ is the borel-sigma algebra.

**Now my book states, this sigma-algebra consits precicely of those sets F, that if we are given all the realisations of $Y_\gamma(\omega)$ for each $\gamma$, we can decide if $\omega \in F$.** Another way of saying this is that even if we don't know $\omega$, but knows the values of the random variables, we can decide the value of $I_F(\omega)$, where I is the indicator function.

Now, my problem is this: how do we show this? What I am able to prove is that indeed all the sets in the sigma algebra have this property, but how do I show that these are the only ones having this property? Below I will prove that indeed all these sets have this property:

Lemma: The sets having the property that knowing $I_F(\omega)$ without knowing $\omega$, is a $\sigma$-algebra.
Proof: 
1. We have that $I_\emptyset(\omega)=0$.

2.We know that $I_{F^c}(\omega)=1-I_F(\omega)$

3.$I_{\cup F_n}=1$, if one $I_F(\omega)=1$, 0 if not.

Lemma: Given the value of each of $Y_\gamma(\omega)$, we can decide if $\omega$ is in the sets $\{\omega \in \Omega: Y_\gamma(\omega)\in B, \gamma \in C, b \in \mathcal{B}\})$.

Proof: Given your set, look at the value of the relevant $Y_\gamma(\omega)$, if $Y_\gamma^{-1}(\{Y_\gamma(\omega)\})$ intersects the set, then $\omega$ is in the set, if not, $\omega$ is not in the set.

These two lemmas show that indeed all the sets in the $\sigma$-algebra have the property that if we have the realisations of our random variables we know wether $\omega \in F$ or not? But how do we know that these are precicely those sets. That if a set is not in this $\sigma$-algebra, it does not have this property?

PS: Here is this directly from the book, first it defines our sigma algebra:

[image]

Then, here is the description I talk about:

[image]

Comment: Do not expect a proof for an "intuitive significance" assertion.  That is why your author used those words.  And, of course, no later proof in the book can use this "intuitive" assertion.  Instead it must use the definition of "generated sigma-algebra".

Comment: @GEdgar Thank yoiu for your answer, but do you mean that this can not be proved? It seemed that even though he used the word intuitive, it is very precise mathematically, that is why I thought it could be proved? And if my proof is correct, I did one part of the proof already, showing that all the sets in our sigma-algebra has this property, but I need to show that these are the only ones aswell.